# Why do blocks disappear incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, html

According to the idea, when changing the **value**, the slider should show or hide blocks in which the **data-value** attribute is greater or less than the output value. But they disappear and do not appear correctly. When I check the caunter value through alert, everything is displayed correctly.

Here is a working example.

```js
var fader = document.querySelector('#fader');

let volInputHandler = function(event) {
    let mass = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
    let output = document.querySelector('#volume');
    let counter = event.target.value;
    output.innerHTML = counter;
    mass.forEach((item, i, mass) => {
         let dataValue = item.getAttribute('data-value');
         if(dataValue < counter){
             item.style.display = 'none';
         }
         else{
             item.style.display = 'block';
         }
    });

}
fader.addEventListener('input', volInputHandler);
```

```css
body {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 100vh;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
span{
 display: inline-block;
}
.slider {
  position: relative;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 300px;
    margin-top:50px;
 }
output {
 position: absolute;
 left: -20px;
 top: -40px;
 padding: 7px 10px;
 background: #76de76;
 color: #fff;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
#fader {
 position: relative;
 left: 3px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 10px;
 background: #76de76;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 outline: none;
 border-radius: 4px;
}

#fader::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: #76de76;
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px #222;
}

.wrapper {
 background-color: grey;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 width: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.block{
 margin: 20px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
 <span>0</span>
 <output name="fader" id="volume">0</output>
 <input id="fader" type="range" name="" value="0" step="10" min="0" max="200">
 <span>200</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="block" data-value="0">0</div>
 <div class="block" data-value="50">50</div>
 <div class="block" data-value="200">200</div>
 <div class="block" data-value="75">75</div>
 <div class="block" data-value="120">120</div>
 <div class="block" data-value="160">160</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `if(dataValue < counter){` - you're comparing *strings* here. I heavily suspect that's the core of your problem.

Comment: Just added this Number(item.getAttribute('data-value')).

Comment: I try to guess: you set display none then select ".block"... but they're not displayed anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert to int

.value and data-value are strings so "90" > "120"

```js
var fader = document.querySelector('#fader');

let volInputHandler = function(event) {
  let mass = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
  let output = document.querySelector('#volume');
  let counter = +event.target.value; // cast to number
  output.innerHTML = counter;
  mass.forEach((item, i, mass) => {
    let dataValue = +item.getAttribute('data-value'); // cast to number
    item.hidden = dataValue < counter
    // item.textContent = dataValue +"<"+ counter + (dataValue < counter)
  });

}
fader.addEventListener('input', volInputHandler);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

output {
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -40px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background: #76de76;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#fader {
  position: relative;
  left: 3px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #76de76;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#fader::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #76de76;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #222;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.block {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <span>0</span>
  <output name="fader" id="volume">0</output>
  <input id="fader" type="range" name="" value="0" step="10" min="0" max="200">
  <span>200</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block" data-value="0">0</div>
  <div class="block" data-value="50">50</div>
  <div class="block" data-value="200">200</div>
  <div class="block" data-value="75">75</div>
  <div class="block" data-value="120">120</div>
  <div class="block" data-value="160">160</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks already found a solution, I had a string data type.

Just added this let dataValue = Number(item.getAttribute('data-value'))